# Opening Notes of another user account in OS X EI Captain

Tags: macos, user-account, recovery, notes.app

I recently replaced my macbook's user account by changing account name from `name1` to `name2`. Now I have to recover some very important notes that I had saved in default **Notes** app but unfortunately didn't sync with cloud.

I have found a folder with old user account name i.e. `name1` at `/Users/name1/` but didn't find any relevant data. Can anybody please recommend me the possible ways of recovering the required data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new user with the exact same name in system preferences as the old one. When given the option, choose to use the old folder as their home folder. Then log in with this user and open the Notes app as that user.

Comment: [not saying you're wrong, just for clarification] If the old user was 501 & the new one will be 503... will it still let you, just by matching the names?

Comment: @NoahL wohoo, seems fantastic triack, why i didn't come up with this solution earlier. Lemme try it first, I will update then.

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry didn't get your point, especially the words `will it still let you, just by matching the names`. let me what?

Comment: If the account name is the same (i.e. The name that would be created for the home folder) MacOS will (or at least used to) ask whether or not you wanted to use the old home folder with the same name.

Comment: Ah, OK. I wasn't sure - thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: @Tetsujin means: will it let you choose to use the old user's folder to use as the home folder, to which I answered in my last comment

Comment: @NoahL your suggested solution got worked, awesome! Thanks.